# Integrating an SQL query into ASP.NET and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

How can I integrate SQL into an ASP.NET C# application?

I'm creating an ASP.NET application and so far my queries to the database has been fairly simple, like:

```
var departmentsQuery = from d in db.Departments
                                   orderby d.Name
                                   select d;
```

I now want to make a more complex SQL query and don't know how to. I am used to normal SQL so I could really need some help formatting this SQL-query to something I can use in my ASP.NET application:

```
select * from Booking AS b, LaneBooking AS lb, Lane AS l
where b.Date = '2017-01-20' AND b.BookingId = lb.BookingId AND lb.LaneId = l.LaneId AND l.Name = 'A'
```

I have noticed that some people use a QueryBuilder, but are there other ways of doing this?

Comment: First thing I notice is that I wouldn't use `*`, I would select individual columns so you know what properties you'll need to extract from the query.

Comment: I recommend using dapper https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net

Comment: Also recommend learning the word `JOIN`

Comment: This question should be re-enabled. There are at least half a dozen options for integrating SQL in C#. The question is concise. We're not being asked to recommend a tool. No-one has provided a link to a duplicate.

Comment: You can use SQL directly in ASP applications, and don't be embarrassed about it. The traditional way is to assign your query text to the commandText property of an ADO command object. A better way is to use Dapper or PetaPoco. There's less code to write, and your results objects are filled for you. Whichever you choose, consider storing your queries in .sql files. SQL in string literals is a weird cultural practice that refuses to die. Access these files as an "Embedded resource" (google for details). I would avoid anything that generates SQL, including your QueryBuilder class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not ready to migrate your data access to an ORM (or micro ORM) like Entity Framework or Dapper, I'd suggest using LINQ to SQL (see [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/linq/linq_sql.htm)) which is pretty straightforward and you don't need to write raw SQL.

If you want to keep writing SQL queries, you can use SqlConnection and SqlCommand, but I'd suggest using QueryBuilder which will make them more flexible (see some [snippets](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13419/SelectQueryBuilder-Building-complex-and-flexible-S)) and maintainable.

I see your first query is in LINQ, but the second one is in SQL. What you want to do in the second query can be easily done done with LINQ; you just have to study more syntax to achieve it. Here's a sample:

```
var bookingQuery =
    from b in db.Booking
    join lb in db.LaneBooking on b.BookingId equals lb.BookingId
    join l in db.Lane on lb.LaneId equals l.LaneId
    where b.Date == "2017-01-20"
    && l.Name == "A"
    select b
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. Did not know it was called Linq. Just one problem though. Lanebooking and Lane gives me this error:
"Lane/LaneBooking not valid in given context"

Comment: If you're using the object 'db' as your LinqToSQLDataContext instance as in your first example, just add 'db.' before your table names and it should work.
I'll edit the answer.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the SqlConnection and SqlCommand objects.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fksx3b4f.aspx#Anchor_1